# mapreduce program: Reducer is not getting called

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know this is very foolish to ask this question here. May be I have got some bad eyes or what. I am not able to understand why my reducer is not getting called even though I have configured it in the driver class. Please help me in identifying the exact place where I have missed something.

### MY DRIVER CLASS

```
public class DPDriver {
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("mapred.textoutputformat.seperator", "-->");
    config.set("fs.file.impl", "com.debajit.assignment.WinLocalFileSystem");

    String inputPath="In\\input.txt";
    Path inPath=new Path(inputPath);
    String outputPath = "C:\\output\\run1";
    Path outPath=new Path(outputPath);

    Job job = new Job(config,"Tst run");
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(DPMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(DPReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inPath );
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);

    System.out.println(job.waitForCompletion(true));

    }
    // enter code here
}
```

### MY MAPPER CLASS

```
package com.debajit.assignment;



public class DPMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

public void map(LongWritable key, Text vals, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    System.out.println(" MAPPER CALLED");
    String valString = vals.toString();
    String tokens[] = valString.split("\\s");

    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length;i++){
        System.out.println(" for loop "+i);
        context.write(new Text(tokens[i]),new IntWritable(1));
    }



}

}
```

### MY REDUCER CLASS

```
package com.debajit.assignment;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class DPReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text>vals, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    System.out.println(" REDUCER CALLD");
    int count=0;
    for(Text t: vals){
        System.out.println("---- Text-------"+ t.toString());
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));


}

}
```

Comment: When I added @Override then it shows an error even though my code is something like this

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text>vals, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException

Comment: Are you getting any error?or does it just pass silently without doing anything?

Comment: No, there is no error. If I remove the @Override annotation, then the reducer doesnot show any error. This reducer is not getting invoked. The override annotation shows some error but I m not sure what error is this?

Comment: There is no error while running the program. The @override annotation when placed, gives the error for the reduce() method in reducer which says " this method must implement or override supertype"

Comment: Found the error. The error was in the Iterable.  I was using Iterable<Text> instead of Iterable<IntWritable>. Thanks Tariq for pushing me to check places where I was missing to look out for. Such a silly mistake..!! Apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reducer class is defined as:

```
public class DPReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
```

So the reducer should have `Input: <Text,IntWritable>` and `Output: <Text,IntWritable>`

But you have defined your reducer as:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text>vals, Context context)
```

which expects `Input: <Text, Iterable<Text>` which does not match what your Reduce class is extending.

That's why you get an error when you add the `@override` annotation.